# Jena: Error upon labels definition for inference rule

Tags: label, jena, rdfs, inference-engine

I am trying to define the following inference rule for Apache Jena. I am using a GeneralRuleReasoner in hybrid mode

```
[ aName:
        (?aRelation meta:refersTo meta:SomeOntologyClass)
        (?test rdfs:type dummy)
           -> (?anotherRelation rdfs:type meta:SomeType)
              (?anotherRelation meta:mainLabel "a"@fr)
              (?anotherRelation meta:mainLabel "b"@en)
              (?anotherRelation meta:mainLabel "c"@de)
              (?anotherRelation rdfs:label "a"@fr)
              (?anotherRelation rdfs:label "b"@en)
              (?anotherRelation rdfs:label "c"@de)
              (?test meta:has ?anotherRelation)
]
```

I also tried the same with single quotes. This fails with this error:

```
[error] - 2020-01-23 17:10:14,655 [play-dev-mode-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-58] ERROR controllers.IndexController - Triple with 4 nodes!
```

I also tried to define it like

```
[ aName:
        (?aRelation meta:refersTo meta:SomeOntologyClass)
        (?test rdfs:type dummy)
           -> (?anotherRelation rdfs:type meta:SomeType)
              (?anotherRelation meta:mainLabel "a" lang:fr)
              (?anotherRelation meta:mainLabel "b" lang:en)
              (?anotherRelation meta:mainLabel "c" lang:de)
              (?anotherRelation rdfs:label "a" lang:fr)
              (?anotherRelation rdfs:label "b" lang:en)
              (?anotherRelation rdfs:label "c" lang:de)
              (?test meta:has ?anotherRelation)
]
```

This does not really work since apparently `lang` only works for query DSL.
I also tried doing the following: I defined another class in the ontology that carries the labels and main labels that I cannot define in the inference rule and add a `onto:` property to 
the derived class.

```
[ aName:
        (?aRelation meta:refersTo meta:SomeOntologyClass)
        (?test rdfs:type dummy)
           -> (?anotherRelation rdfs:type meta:SomeType)
              (?anotherRelation meta:refersTo onto:UtilityClassCarryngLabels)
              (?test meta:has ?anotherRelation)

]
```

This works in the sense that the inference rule **IS** created **BUT** when tried to query (SPARQL) for the triples, neither the labels not the main labels for the derived class came up. Nevertheless, I can see that `anotherR` **has** been correlated with `test`.

So my question is: **What is the right way to define labels(including language specification) in an inference rule?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jena **does not** support language specific literal definition for inference rules. To overcome this:

1. You could define a custom `BaseBuiltin` that creates language specific node manually:

   NodeFactory.createLiteral(string.getLiteral.getLexicalForm, lang.getLiteral.getLexicalForm)
2. Create another class that holds the language specific labels you want and refer to this other class. This will not be enough though since you're going to have to create **another** inference rule that assigns the labels of new class to the referrer class. The relation would look like this:
   From the inference rule

   a meta:refersTo b

In the ontology definition

```
b rdfs:label "foo"@de , "bar"@fr ;
```

In another inference rule

```
?referrer meta:refersTo b
    -> [(?class rdfs:label ?label)
                  <- (b rdfs:label ?label)]
```